# Align div vertically center

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

As the title says, i have a div that i want to align center vertically.

```
<body>
<div class="container" id="names_wrapper">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="images/feat1" class="img-responsive img-circle">
                <h2 class="text-center">Jammu</h2>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="images/feat2" class="img-responsive img-circle">
                <h2 class="text-center">Kashmir</h2>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="images/feat3" class="img-responsive img-circle">
                <h2 class="text-center">Ladakh</h2>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

i tried to wrap that div in a another div with height of `100%` and applied `vertical-align: center` property but it doesn't work.

i'm using twitter bootstrap. Whats' the solution?

Comment: it's vertical-align: middle;

Comment: which div you are trying to center? and simply vertical align
:middle will not do the job

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are trying to center the `.row` div inside the `.container`

```
.container {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Hope it will help